# Jail break detection for Flutter iOS apps

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

During the testing  found that the ios application does not have a jailbreak protection required to block the app running on a jailbreak device.

Any suggestion how to implement below things for my flutter APP for iOS
It is highly recommended to implement the below method.

```
• Try to find the presence of Cydia
 • Attempt to find existence of CydiaSubstrate, the framework that allows installation of third-party patches 
• Attempt to access directories that should not be available to an app without escalated privileges (such as /bin/bash, /etc/apt)
 • Try to find symbolic links to usually unavailable directories
 • Or, attempt to write to a directory where that usually wouldn’t be possible
```

Comment: This question is not suitable for SoF. Try asking on a specific iOS software related websites/forums as it's not part of Flutter development nor iOS's.

Comment: A bit off topic here. Anyways, you should attempt to detect components of the jailbreak like /Applications/Cydia.app but do keep in mind various jailbreaks may have different package managers others than Cydia. You really should do some research on the bootstrap of jailbreaks.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 plugs in pub.dev that do the job for you.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_jailbreak_detection
https://pub.dev/packages/trust_fall

They both utilize existing native libs
Rootbeer https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer for Android and
DTTJailbreakDetection https://github.com/thii/DTTJailbreakDetection for iOs,

so you might consider connecting those directly into your project.